# Why do the workers stop working inside a pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

In order to parallelize the processing of some data I want to create 2 different workers. They each use a different data source. Therefore I do call them individually with a worker pool of one worker. (see Code)

I want to use a queue for each of them individually to get the input data. The very first runthrough works fine. But If I add more jobs for the worker, the worker does not process them. You can also see the list of jobs getting bigger.

What am I doing wrong here? The desired output would be a print of each job that I put in the queue.

You can check the code below which was written in Python 3.7 that should reproduce the error.

Bonus Question: If I take away the "time.sleep(0.1)" in the **main** section, and run the script in PowerShell, the script finishes before printing the result of the second worker. How to use .join here in order to wait for the processes to run through?

```
# Creates workers
def worker1(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get(True)
        print('I am Worker 1: I started working, len of the queue is : ' + str(q.qsize()))
        print(item)

        # Simulating a long calculation
        time.sleep(1)


def worker2(q):
    while True:
        item = q.get(True)
        print('I am Worker 2: I started working, len of the queue is :  ' + str(q.qsize()))
        print(item)

        # Simulating a long calculation
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Configs
    n_workers = 2

    # Define Queues
    q1 = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()
    q2 = multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()

    the_queue = [q1, q2]
    the_pool = []
    workers = [worker1, worker2]

    # Creating one worker for each Queue
    for i in range(n_workers):
        the_pool.append(multiprocessing.Pool(1, workers[i],(the_queue[i],)))

    # First Run
    for i in range(n_workers):
        the_queue[i].put("hello " + str(i))
        print('I just put in a value, len of the queue is :  ' + str(the_queue[i].qsize()))

    # Give some time before adding new tasks
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # Next Runs
    for ii in range(10):
        for i in range(n_workers):
            the_queue[i].put("hello " + str(i))
            print('I just put in a value, len of the queue is :   ' + str(the_queue[i].qsize()))
```

Comment: I believe that passing parameters to Pool in the constructor only sets up the pool. You need to call methods of the pool to make anything happen in parallel, eg map()

Comment: At first I thought this as well, but the workers start working once, As you can see from the prints they do. So I dont get why they are not stuck in the while True loop

Comment: Just because something seems to work doesn’t mean it is the right way to go. Please read the documentation on the constructor and methods of Pool.

Comment: @DennisHügle: Read [The following example demonstrates the use of a pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.successful)

Comment: If you want to have workers on the other end of a queue you will be better off with `multiprocessing.Process`. You can create instances of these which run a target callable, which like you have, can block on a queue. (One technique to terminate these processes is to finally send a `None` onto the queue and have the process return when it sees the `None`)